# Python 3 inheritance equivalent statements

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, super

From the documentation here, it claims that super().method(arg) does the same thing as: super(C, self).method(arg).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

```
class shape(object):
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.shapeType = type

class coloredShape1(shape):
    def __init__(self, type, color):
        super().__init__(type)
        self.shapeColor = color

class coloredShape2(shape):
    def __init__(self, type, color):
        super(shape, self).__init__(type)
        self.shapeColor = color

circle = shape("circle")
blueRectangle = coloredShape1("rectangle", "blue")
redSquare = coloredShape2("square", "blue")
```

There are no issues with the blueRectangle creation, however, the redSquare line throws the following expection:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    redSquare = coloredShape2("square", "blue")
File "test.py", line 12, in __init__
  super(shape, self).__init__(type)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I'm not understanding the difference between the two.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed the wrong class to `super()`, and so you called `object.__init__`, not `shape.__init__`.

```
class coloredShape2(shape):
    def __init__(self, type, color):
        super(coloredShape2, self).__init__(type)
        self.shapeColor = color
```